# Permission Denied Error in GitHub Codespace Execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, permission-denied, github-codespaces

I've been working on a project using GitHub Codespaces, and everything was running smoothly until recently. Within the first hour of usage, the Codespace was functioning as expected. However, after approximately one hour, I encountered the following error message:

/workspaces/javascript (main) $ 01_basics/test.js
bash: 01_basics/test.js: Permission denied

I've tried investigating possible causes such as file permissions, user settings, or potential changes in the Codespace environment, but haven't been able to pinpoint the exact source of the problem.

I expected that by ensuring the correct file permissions and reviewing the Codespace settings, I would be able to resolve the permission denied error and successfully run the test.js file without any issues.